# Angular Web call API in same IIS without using public IP

Tags: angular, iis, .net-core, deployment

I have 2 webapp on IIS 1 Fontend code with Angular 6 and 1 API with .netcore. Can i call API from Fontend without using public IP(different port)?

Comment: This question is very broad. Yes you can, can you please elaborate on what you've tried and what didn't work ?

Comment: @Nicolas like the Brando Zhang answer below when working on client it became localhost in client machine, it not recognize that will be localhost on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to use angualr application to call the backend angular in clinet user's browser, it will not work.

Since the client-side angualr applciation is running on the user's browser without using public IP address, it will send the request to local's localhost application not server's application.

Comment: can i deploy it became 1 IIS

Comment: In my opinon, there is no way to achieve this, as my reply says the codes is running on the client not the server, so the the url or ip address you have used is wrong. It will always return 404 page not found error,

Comment: Thank you, I had founded solution to do this issue, we can deploy both fontend Angular and Backend .Netcore API in the same IIS